# How to check if websocket user is authenticated when subscribe a channel?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket

I have websocket config class with :

```
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
            config.enableSimpleBroker("/topics");
            config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");        
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/notifications").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
```

As well as `ClientInboundChannel`:

```
@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.setInterceptors(new ChannelInterceptorAdapter() {

        @Override
        public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {

            StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

            final String xAuthToken = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader(ManipulatesHeaders.X_AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER);

            if (xAuthToken == null) {
                return message;
            }

            final UserDetails userDetails = authService.getUserDetails(xAuthToken);

            if (StompCommand.CONNECT == accessor.getCommand()) {
                final WebSocketPrincipal principal = (...)

                userRegistry.registerUser(principal, message);
                accessor.setUser(principal);
            }

            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to send a welcome messsage to every user that subscribe a particular channel. It's obvious that It might be achieved by creating a class that implements `ApplicationListener<SessionSubscribeEvent>` and provides

```
@Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final SessionSubscribeEventevent) {
      StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
}
```

Second approach is to perform similar thing in aforementioned `ClientInboundChannel` (it's the same).

The problem is, that there is no `simpUser` header in a `message` when a user send a stomp `SUBSCRIBE`.

Process is as follows: User sends stomp `CONNECT`, this line is executed: `accessor.setUser(principal)` and at this point `message` has properly set`simpUser` header. But when stomp `SUBSCRIBE` message is received in `preSend`, the `StompHeaderAccessor` does not have `simpUser` header. Thus I am not able to asses whether user is already authenticated or not.

So how could I check if a user that sent a `SUBSCRIBE` message is already authenticated or not ? (and why authenticated user does not send `simpUser` header)

Answer (score 1):

In your websocket configuration class change your extend to `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`

then you can set your security as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry message) {
    message
      .nullDestMatcher().permitAll()
      .simpDestMatchers("/app/**").authenticated()
      .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/topics/**").authenticated()
      .anyMessage().denyAll();
}
```

if you get the error `Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found` you will have to override `sameOriginDisabled in the websocket configuration class

```
  @Override
  protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
      return true;
  }
```

for more information on websocket security:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/websocket.html

Comment: So bascially the idea is, that by `.authenticated()` I don't have to deal with any 'token via stomp authentication' because it's done by spring security. And basically I can create `onApplicationEvent(final SessionSubscribeEvent event)` for a particular channel subscription because I know that if user was able to reach here, must be authenticated. Am I correct ?

Comment: That is correct. Provided that you are setting the security principle through some type of authentication provider (typically `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`) spring security will do the checking and will not allow unauthenticated subscribers to send/receive messages.

Comment: I do use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`. I keep getting `message:Failed to send message to ExecutorSubscribableChannel[clientInboundChannel]; nested exception is org.springframework.security.web.csrf.MissingCsrfTokenException\c Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.` any idea what could be the reason or how could I debug ?

Comment: Since you `setAllowedOrigin("*")` you will have to override `sameOriginDisabled` (See my modified answer)